# LASSO: Dual form problem.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, regression

I would like to know the procedure, step by step, to arrive at the dual form of the optimization problem for lasso:

From:
\begin{equation}\label{ridge2}
\hat{\beta}^{lasso}=\min_{\beta}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-\beta_{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\beta_{j}X_{ij}\right)^2} \quad \mathrm{s.a} \quad \sum_{j=1}^{p}|\beta_{j}| \leq t
\end{equation}

To:
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\beta}^{lasso}=\min_{\beta} \left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-\beta_{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\beta_{j}X_{ij}\right)^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{p}|\beta_{j}| \right\rbrace
\end{equation}

In all the books I have seen they say that the two forms are equivalent, using the Lagrange multipliers, but I don't know why. That part is always omitted. It may be trivial, but I don't understand it.

Comment: It’s not trivial, but it is well known.  It comes down to the KKT conditions.  A great book that explains it is “Convex Optimization” by Boyd and Vandenberghe, which one can download for free on the internet.

Comment: The problems are only equivalent for a specific value of $\lambda$, which depends on $y$ and $X$.